# Delaying Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to delay the post of the below form by 3 seconds and have an image pop up.

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="">
     <input type="hidden" name="inp1" method="post" value="<?php echo $var1 - $var2; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="inp2" method="post" value="<?php echo $var3 - $var4; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="inp3" method="post" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="inp4" value="Test" />
</form>
```

I am trying to get the delay part working first and have tried using `Javascript` in the HTML head part of my `php` file:

```
$('test').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 30000); // in milliseconds
});
```

This currently isn't giving any delay. Any ideas?

Comment: 3 seconds = 3000 ms , you have 30s delay on your example

Comment: use $('#test').submit();  and 3000 ms=3sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would switch things up a bit, rather than using a submit button I would change it to a regular button and pass the form in the button.  You don't need the submit button at all.

`<input type="button" name="inp4" value="Test" onclick="myfunction(form)" />`

Then the function

```
  function myfunction(form) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            form.submit();
        },30000);
  }
```

that should do the trick.  No jQuery needed

Comment: parameter should be (form)

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to add `#` with $("#test")

```
$('#test').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 3000); // in milliseconds
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/muhammadusmaann/xa9mfgqa/)

Comment: even copying the code directly from the demo this just seems to refresh the page with no delay.